# Pipeline repository dependency

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, repository

When you create new CI pipeline you can add agent job and agentless one.

My first question is: why is necessary to select a repository while you create an agentless job? Why is so repository dependent?

Is it possible to create a CI pipeline without selecting a repository?

Thank you in advance

Expecting to create an agentless CI without selecting a git repository in Azure Devops

Comment: Are you creating pipelines using YAML or using classic editor?

Comment: I'm using classic editor but i have tried even YAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create a (YAML) CI pipeline without a repository. In the YAML case it has to store the YAML file somewhere (right: in the repo).

In your case, for an agentless job, just use an "empty" repo with only the YAML, which is then perfectly versioned through git ;-)

### Edit

Based on you recent comments (below):

> I got multiple repositories and in the master branch i configure a
> verification CI.  e.x I got repo x with x_CI-verify and x_CI-build
> repo y with y_CI-verify and y_CI-build and so on.
>
> In branch master for each repo i should configure each verify CI.  To
> avoid configuring one by one for each repo the right CI i want to
> create this 'master CI' which is build, get the repo name(x name) and
> build the x_CI-verify.

The best approach is to work with templates.
These templates can then be referenced from your X, Y, etc repos.

[[image: template example]]

You still have create an `azure-pipeline.yml` in the X, Y repo and use the template:

```yaml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: Build-Templates

extends:
  template: apps.yml@templates
```

More info about templates, for example the use with [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#parameters), check [the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops).

Comment: When you create a pipeline you must select e repo. My scenario is:
I have multiple repositories with multiple CI pipelines. I want to create lets call a master CI which dynamically based on some inputs can find and build the right one.
While the pipelines are dependent on repository makes this scenario not feasible.

Comment: @user3224701 OK, I editted my answer. But I think I'm stilling missing some details to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your time.
 Let me be more specific:
I got multiple repositories and in the master branch i configure a verification CI. 
e.x
I got repo x with x_CI-verify and x_CI-build
repo y with y_CI-verify and y_CI-build
and so on.
In branch master for each repo i should configure each verify CI.
To avoid configuring one by one for each repo the right CI i want to create this 'master CI' which is build, get the repo name(x name) and build the x_CI-verify.
I hope to be clear

Comment: @user3224701 you can achieve this by creating a centralized _generic_ template that would hold `generic_CI-verify` and `generic_CI-build`. All repo x or repo y need to do is to call that _generic_ template and pass in their parameters within their YAML pipeline. Let me know if you'd like a sample of this.

Comment: @user3224701 this was already a bit in my answer, but I tried to rewrite it to your needs

Comment: Thank you guys for your support.
I tried on my own but without result. 
I have seen more tutorials and I'm confused how to call this generic_CI-Verify and pass variable value.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to create a Pipeline without selecting a repository. The reason is that the repository needs to be selected on the [Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops) level, not on job level. This means that when we create a new Pipeline, it is configured to have multiple stage(s) and those stage(s) can have multiple jobs (agent/agentless). The repository needs to be added to add flexibility to the pipeline which should be able to refer an existing script or a YAML file in the source control that was configured earlier.

If in the future Azure DevOps looks to add feature to create standalone agentless jobs, then it would make sense not to have an option for repositories.